# Dropping column during for loop - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two basic DataFrames, and I combine them into a list called dfCombo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12,24).reshape(3,4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
dfCombo = [df, df2]
```

They are both 3x4 DF's with 4 columns A, B, C, D.

I am able to use a for loop to add a column to both the DF with the following code:

```
for df3 in dfCombo:
    df3['E'] = df3['A'] + df3['B']
```

With this both df and df2 will both have an new column E. However when I try to drop a column using this method with the below code, no columns are dropped:

```
for df3 in dfCombo:
    df3 = df3.drop('B', axis = 1)
```

or

```
for df3 in dfCombo:
    df3 = df3.drop(columns = ['B'])
```

If I use the same code on a single DF the column is dropped:

```
df2 = df2.drop('B', axis = 1)
```

or

```
df2 = df2.drop(columns = ['B'])
```

If you could help me understand what is going on I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `inplace=True`:

```
for df3 in dfCombo:
    df3.drop('B', axis = 1, inplace=True)
```

Which returns:

```
   A   C   D   E
0  0   2   3   1
1  4   6   7   9
2  8  10  11  17

    A   C   D   E
0  12  14  15  25
1  16  18  19  33
2  20  22  23  41
```

The default `inplace=False` is intended for assigning back to the original dataframe, because it returns a new copy. However `inplace=True` operates on the same copy and returns `None`, therefore there is no need to assign back to the original dataframe.